# How to access a list of tibble to check whether "UTF-8" and run import R

Tags: r, utf-8, import, tibble, readr

**TARGET :**
**Check whether a list of files have same encoding before import and rbind ,if not the same STOP run**

```
# files list & check encoding
FL_PATH <- list.files(path,pattern = "*.csv",full.name = T)
library(readr)
lapply(FL_PATH,guess_encoding)

# if there is "UTF-8" , STOP RUN , if "Shift_JIS" , RUN the next scripts below :

# import
library(rio)
DT <- rbindlist(lapply(FL_PATH ,import,sep=",",setclass = "data.table"))

# OVER 500 rows to run if the files are same encoding to rbind
DT[,"NEW_COL":="A"]
DT[,"NEW_COL_2":="B"]
.....

# result of --lapply(FL_PATH,guess_encoding)
> lapply(FL_PATH,guess_encoding)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  encoding  confidence
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 Shift_JIS       0.8 
2 GB18030         0.76
3 Big5            0.46

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  encoding  confidence
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 GB18030         0.82
2 UTF-8       0.8 
3 Big5            0.44
```

- **Problem 1** : How to access the variables of the result of lapply readr
  to detect UTF-8 and STOP (have to revise the encoding outside R if
  UTF-8 exist ?)
- **Problem 2** : How to connect the large numbers of normal processing scripts
  with "if & STOP run" ?

Comment: Instead of going through all the results, how about letting `lapply` return only the top result? Try `sapply(FL_PATH,function(x) guess_encoding(x)$encoding[1])`

Comment: Thankyou Rohit , thats exactly the way to ACCESS tibble , and readr  raise the first one as highest percentage . But lets say  grepl("UTF-8",sapply(FL_PATH,function(x) guess_encoding(x)$encoding[1]))    return me TRUE and FALSE  , i have no idea how to connect to import / not import approach .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the most probable encoding:

```
enc <- sapply(FL_PATH,function(x) guess_encoding(x)$encoding[1])
```

Then, if any of the files are UTF-8, stop execution.

```
if(any(grepl('UTF-8',enc)))
  stop('UTF-8 present') # This will stop with an error if true
# Now, read files and rbind
dlist <- lapply(FL_PATH,read_csv)
DT <- rbindlist(dlist)
```

Comment: My god , best way to apply if and STOP and checking function in the whole script